# Do questions asking for solution in any of multiple software products need more focus?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, multiple-questions

Every Stack Exchange site dealing with software seems to attract some questions that describe a goal and seek a solution in a form like:

> How do I do X in any one (or more) of products A, B, C or D?

Should the above be considered as one question and left Open or should it be Closed as "Needs more focus" for effectively asking four questions?

> - How do I do X in product A?
> - How do I do X in product B?
> - How do I do X in product C?
> - How do I do X in product D?

Comment: Seems like something to decide on a per-site basis.

Comment: @Helmar with many of us participating in more than one software site I thought it may have been possible to get some pan-site or site-independent views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Super User, (and probably many other sites) - it's a good idea to focus on a *problem*.

As such, to me a good question would be "How do I do X on platform Y (optionally with constraints Z)?".

Since in many cases there's different ways to flay the proverbial feline, a question asking about ways to do something with multiple products is *likely* to be too broad, and hard to write a focused answer for, but it depends.

Answer (score 0):

My concern with questions of the form:

> How do I do X in any one (or more) of products A, B, C or D?

has always been that they lay the groundwork for a poll of which product is best to use for doing X.

Such a question invites opinions from different community members, expressed in answers and votes, as to which they think is best.

I think polls and other opinion-seeking questions are the antithesis of focused Q&A.

Consequently, in every case that comes to mind, I think such a question should be focused into one or more questions of the form:

> How do I do X in product Y?

Each community may advocate whether closing such questions on their own sites is appropriate.  Personally, I think that should be the case on each site I participate in.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we need a general network policy for this matter. Each site can define a policy on their per-site meta.

I could imagine there are cases where there are multiple software tools to accomplish a certain goal. For example there are many GIS programs out there, which can all basically do the same things. Often there are community members that are capable of working with these multiple tools.

When OP indicates that they are capable in certain tools an answer to the question could focus on any of those tools, and be a valid answer. I'd say bonus points to the answer that compares multiple tools and identifies the best / most efficient way to handle OP's problem.

Comment: I agree that  most, if not all, GIS Professionals are more than capable of working with multiple GIS products.  However, when trying to answer a GIS question, the answer I will give, or clarifications that I would seek in order to answer, will vary depending on what software product is being used.  I think the Q&A is much cleaner when questions asked and answered, and clarifications sought and supplied, can remain focused on a single product being used rather than multiple products that might possibly be used.

Comment: That is a totally valid point @PolyGeo, but for that matter alone I wouldn't opt for a blanket ban on any question asking to do something in *any* GIS product. Now I'm not that knowledgable on GIS matters, but I assume there are more sofisticated cases where Product A drastically outperforms Products B, C and D. I think it is very valid to ask for a solution in any product in such a case. As for something simple as drawing a boundary for example, adding multiple products only adds confusion. So all in all it isn't completely black and white, and nuance is needed.

Comment: It sounds like you’re condoning the setting up a poll on which of multiple product options meets a particular requirement or set of requirements the best. To me that’s the antithesis of focused Q&A. I think the best questions for Stack Exchange sites are relatively fine-grained.

Comment: @PolyGeo, no definetly not any polls! Ill try to expand my answer when I have a bit more time, this back and forth in the comments makes things harder to grasp.